# parse a list of strings to list of XDocument

Tags: c#, xml, vb.net, parsing

I have following C# code which works fine. it  calls a method of webservice to extract xml data.

```
List<string> ContactListByDate = DataServiceClient.GetRecsByDate(yesterday, now).ToList();
        List<XDocument> students = ContactListByDate.Select(XDocument.Parse).ToList();
```

but when I convert it to vb.net as below, it throws an error saying 
Overload resolution failed because no accessible 'Parse' accepts this number of arguments. What am I missing?

```
Dim ContactListByDate As List(Of String) = DataServiceClient.GetRecsByDateRange(yesterday, now).ToList()
Dim students As List(Of XDocument) = DataServiceContactListByDate.[Select](XDocument.Parse).ToList()
```

Answer (score -1):

C# to VB.NET converters don't do that good of a job converting LINQ/Lambda queries. If I were manually converting it, it may come out to this:

```
Dim students As List(Of XDocument) = ContactListByDate.Select(Function(obj) XDocument.Parse(obj)).ToList()
```

To explain, you basically create an inline function passing whatever argument is returned from `ContactListByData` and then calling XDocument.Parse on that argument to return your new XDocument with the parsed data.